# Old ceiling fan was going bad but still worked. New one does not work at all

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

Our old ceiling fan worked for a time but was going bad. So we took it down and bought a new one. We followed the manual and hooked up the wires: green to ground, white to white and black and and blue to the hot black wire. But still it does not seem to work. We checked the wires and there is about 119 to 120 AC coming through the wires. Could there be a tiny amount of voltage that we need before the fan would turn on?

This makes no sense to me if the old one worked perfectly fine whats the problem with the new one?

By the way we did take it back and exchange it because we thought it might have been defective.

Thanks ahead of time for any help on this really been bugging me.

Comment: the hot black should go down to the switch then comes back as white or blue and goes to the fan. the white in the ceiling box goes to the fan. all you need is a phase tester to find out

Comment: Are you using  a wall switch  or the fan pull change?  Make sure the reverse/forward switch on the fan isn't "in the middle"

Comment: We are just using a pull chain no switch.